# Is it possible to set seed in the elrm package?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, seeding

I am quite new to r, and am using the elrm package for exact logistic regression (ELR).  I would like for it to be possible to replicate my results, so from my research, it seems I need to set a seed for the simulation.

My dataset has to do with criminal reoffending related to prior record characteristics, risk level on a standardized assessment, and how our program affects the rate of reoffending.  So, TREATMENT is my primary independent variable of interest, and the recidivism rate (RECID_sum/case_sum) is my dependent variable.

I have tried this a few different ways.

First, I ran

```
set.seed(66672)
```

After running this, I run the below code for the ELR:

```
m.treatment <- elrm(formula = RECID_sum / case_sum ~ TREATMENT + FDRUGVSP +
FPROPVSP + FELEVENTVSP + RISK + street_time + TREATMENT, interest =~ TREATMENT, 
iter=100000, dataset=final, burnIn=100)
```

And each time I got different results, even after being sure to set the seed again before running the code a second time.

I also tried the following:

```
m.treatment <- elrm(formula = RECID_sum / case_sum ~ TREATMENT + FDRUGVSP + 
FPROPVSP + FELEVENTVSP + RISK + street_time + TREATMENT, interest =~ TREATMENT, 
iter = 100000, dataset = final, burnIn = 100); set.seed(66672)
```

but received different results each time I ran it.  I did not receive any errors running this code.

I've done some research on setting a seed for Monte Carlo simulations generally, but that approach does not seem applicable here.  There doesn't seem to be information out there about setting a seed for ELR in the elrm package.  I may be missing it because of my relative inexperience with r and I may not know exactly what I am looking for.  Normally I use SPSS, which is so clunky and unfortunately can't do ELR in a way that makes sense.

Any help you can offer is much appreciated, and pardon my newness to r if this is a simple answer.

Comment: Use proper formatting http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think so. Digging into the [C++ source code](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/elrm_1.2.2.tar.gz) shows that the underlying code is using the system [`rand()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html):

```
## binomMCMC.cpp, line 31:    
double runif = (float) rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

This in itself is a little bit troubling, as R's built-in random number generators (which can be accessed from within C++ code)  are [generally considered to be more reliable, and faster, than Unix rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466437/can-rcpp-replace-unif-function-in-r).

What's worse is that the initialization of the RNG seems to be hardcoded:

```
## binomMCMC.cpp, line 251
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

I think your only option here would be to contact the maintainers (`maintainer("elrm")`) ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.